# improvement on import ... from

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hey I was trying to the the following :
I'm working on Vue.js and everytime you need a component you need to import them to be able to use them.
So I was thinking to make module with every path of components like this:

```
export default {
  bar: '@/components/chart/bar.vue',
  dashboard: '@/components/chart/dashboard.vue',
  gantt: '@/components/chart/gantt.vue',
  // ... other path
}
```

And use the module like this in some files .vue for exemple:

```
<template>
  <!-- ... some code -->
</template>

<script>
import path from '@/theGoodPath'
import bar from path.bar

// ... some code
</script>
```

But it seems that it doesn't work and I think it's a shame because this way, we could manage more conveniently the path for components and we need to make changes only on 1 file, if needed.

What do you think?

EDIT : I try to use re-export, it doesn't work also when I change from :

```
<script>
import bar from '@/components/chart/bar'
import gantt from '@/components/chart/gantt'
import dashboard from '@/components/chart/dashboard'
import menuNav from '@/components/mini components/menuNav'

// some code
</script>
```

to this :

```
<script>
import { bar, gantt, dashboard, menuNav } from '@/path.js'

// some code
</script>
```

it doesn't work in the second case.
As path.js contains:

```
export { default as bar } from '@/components/chart/bar'
export { default as dashboard } from '@/components/chart/dashboard'
export { default as gantt } from '@/components/chart/gantt'
export { default as menuNav } from '@/components/mini components/menuNav'
```

Comment: I think you should use an IDE for development because this type of issue is really not important when you have the ability to refactor and safe-replace.

Comment: `import` statement cannot be used in embedded scripts.

Comment: You make a point but I like to use Sublime to edit

Comment: @ricardoorellana it is valid syntax for Vue _Single File Component_ (SFC). Browsers also start supporting [`"module"` type `<scripts>` with `import`](https://medium.com/dev-channel/es6-modules-in-chrome-canary-m60-ba588dfb8ab7).

Comment: @Danny I've added link to live demo, check my answer :) If it doesn't work for you, please provide error log. Probably you need to update babel config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use re-export for that.

```
# file: @/theGoodPath
export { default as bar } from '@/components/chart/bar.vue'
export { default as dashboard } from '@/components/chart/dashboard.vue'
export { default as gantt } from '@/components/chart/gantt.vue'
```

Than usage will look like this:

```
<template>
  <!-- ... some code -->
</template>

<script>
import { bar } from '@/theGoodPath'

// ... some code, use `bar` here
</script>
```

Learn more about re-export here - http://jamesknelson.com/re-exporting-es6-modules/

---

Check **[live demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/z3wq1mwpv4?module=%2Fsrc%2Fpath.js)**